# How do i get the last saved image on hard disk?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this line:

```
imageList = Directory.GetFiles(@"e:\webbrowserimages\", "*.bmp").ToList();
```

This is a List

But i want now just one string variable single variable not a list that will contain the last saved image file on the hard disk.

If for example i have 10 images on the hard disk and the first one is: Image0.bmp then Image1.bmp so the string variable will contain Image10.bmp 
And then if on my hard disk there are 24 images then the variable string should contain Image24.bmp

Comment: Is "for example"  section describing exactly what you looking for ("natural sort") or it is just random example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this to get the latest bitmap file in the direcotry,

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"e:\webbrowserimages\");

var myFile = (from f in directory.GetFiles("*.bmp")                   
                orderby f.LastWriteTime descending
                select f).First();
```

Unless no other parameter is available better not relying on file name in filtering latest image.